# Best practices for including Object Detection API in project?

Tags: git, tensorflow, github, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I'm using the TensorFlow Object Detection API with a custom dataset in my own repository (following the project structuring recommended on the [Training Custom Object Detector](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) guide).

What the best practices for including the [`tensorflow/models`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) repository (and its dependencies) in my own project? Should I be using a git submodule, a git subtree, cloning the repo and including/not including it in my project repository when pushing to GitHub, etc?

Would like clarification on this. Thanks.